# What is the JSF behaviour, if you bind the same backing bean property to two input fields in the same form?

Tags: jsf

Is there a defined behaviour in JSF, if two input fields are bound to the same session scoped Backing Bean property.

Here is my code snippet

```
<h:form id="myForm">
   <h:inputText id="field1" value="#{TheBackingBean.theProperty}" />
   <h:inputText id="field2" value="#{TheBackingBean.theProperty}" />

   <h:commandButton id="continueButton" action="#{TheBackingBean.doSomething}" />
</h:form>
```

My question: If field1 and field2 receive different values, what will be bound to the backing bean property? Is this even allowed?

I know this is a crude scenario. My motivation is, that we have htmlunit tests running for our application. In our JSF application we want to use a cool ajaxified custom component. This doesnt work together very well with htmlunit. So my idea was, I just put in a hidden field that binds to the same property. The unit test then fills the hidden field instead of the "real" thing.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this kind of code is allowed, but I am not sure of the value of *theProperty* after the submission. What I think is that JSF will do the following:

```
TheBackingBean.setTheProperty(field1.value);
TheBackingBean.setTheProperty(field2.value);
```

However, nothing - as far as I know - specifies the order of the setter calls. Thus, after the *update values* JSF phase, you will not be sure if *theProperty* will be equal to *field1.value* or *field2.value*.

Concerning your scenario, you say that you want to bind the same property to an inputText and an **hidden**Text. As the hiddenText will not submit its value, unlike the inputText, this problem will not occur. Indeed, if you have this kind of JSF code:

```
<h:inputText id="field1" value="#{TheBackingBean.theProperty}"/>
<h:inputHidden id="field2" value="#{TheBackingBean.theProperty}"/>
```

then JSF will only do:

```
TheBackingBean.setTheProperty(field1.value);
```

during the submission phase.