# h:inputText value inside rich:modalPanel not binding to backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam

When I click the save button, 'addCompany' action is called but when I debug and see the value of instance variable companyName in my backing bean, its showing null. I think I am doing some real silly mistake.

**Modal XHTML**: Included in form tag of another xhtml.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

        <rich:modalPanel id="AddDmpCompanyModalId"
                             showWhenRendered="#{companyAdminAction.showAddCompanyModal}"
                             width="500"
                             height="340"
                             autosized="true">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Add Company"/>
                </f:facet>


                <a4j:outputPanel id="addDmpCompanyInputPanel">

                            <label style="font-weight:bold;margin-top:5px">Name: </label>
                            <h:inputText id="companyName"  value="#{companyAdminAction.companyName}"/>

                                <a4j:commandLink id="submit-add-company-name-link"
                                                 immediate="true"
                                                 action="#{companyAdminAction.addCompany()}"
                                                 styleClass="button"
                                                 reRender="AddDmpCompanyModalId,addDmpCompanyInputPanel"
                                                 limitToList="true">
                                    <span class="inner-button">Save</span>
                                </a4j:commandLink>


                </a4j:outputPanel>

            </rich:modalPanel>

    </ui:composition>
```

**Backing Bean (Seam Component)**

```
Name("companyAdminAction")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class CompanyAdmin {

    private String companyName;     

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

      public void addCompany() {
    // On click of save debugger comes here, but shows the value of          
      //companyName as null 
     }  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the reason is very simple: you're using `immediate=true` in your `<a4j:commandLink/>`. This option makes JSF invoke the `addCompany()` function **BEFORE** values are converted and the model updated.

The solution is equally simple: remove the `immediate=true` attribute from `<a4j:commandLink/>`.

Comment: Actually this was part of the problem, I also had to add a rich: modal attribute domElementAttachment="parent" , I read about it online but still confused, it worked anyways. If you can elaborate about this attribute here, that would be great. I like your answer with simple explanation. Thank you! :).

Comment: `domElementAttachment` tells richfaces where to position the html of the `<rich:modalPanel/>` (which is a popup). Usually popups are positioned as children of the `<body>` tag because otherwise they could be overlapped by other elements. In your case the popup contains input elements but no `<form>` tag so it renders the elements **OUTSIDE** a form and that's why they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the composite component is inside in a form, and in the form you have another component bound to the `companyName` attribute of your bean. Add a form for your `rich:modalPanel` and move it outside the actual form where is contained. Your code should be like this:

```html
<rich:modalPanel id="AddDmpCompanyModalId" ... >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Add Company"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="addDmpCompanyInputPanel">
            ...
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

More info:

- [What is the JSF behaviour, if you bind the same backing bean property to two input fields in the same form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1037725/1065197)